# Hide files and directories starting with '.' in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus

When viewing the home directory with Nautilus, files and directories starting with '.' are now visible.

Some examples of files/dirs that could earlier only be viewed by running `ls -a`, but are now even visible in Nautilus are - `.bashhistory`, `.git`, `.gitignore`, `.config` etc.

I am not sure how this happened and could not find an option to revert this under Nautilus `preferences` menu.

Help in reverting to old system would be appreciated.

Comment: Press Ctrl+H. I don't know what is "Gnome file explorer" though.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks did the trick. I'll close the question. What should I call the default file explorer that comes with ubuntu? Since that is what I meant by Gnome file explorer.

Comment: It is called "Nautilus"

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks I'll edit the question and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle hide/unhide hidden files and directories in Nautilus press Ctrl+H.